# Showing preview of Font Size in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, fullscreen, preview

I am trying to create an application wherein you can write text in a textbox, chose the font, color, etc.
All of this will be shown in a preview box next to it and when the user clicks "Go Live", the same content from the preview box will be shown fullscreen.
There comes the problem.

If the user types "Hello World" and choses font-size as "8", the preview box might show that the text is taking up the whole screen. But when I click "Go Live", the font-size on the fullscreen is still 8 and the text looks very tiny.

I figured that I will somehow have to find a ratio of the sizes of the preview box and the screen resolution and map the font-size from the preview to the fullscreen. The following algorithm seems to work :

```
multiply_factor = (int)monitor_width/preview_box_width;
add_factor = (int)(1st digit of the decimal part of the above division);
live_Screen_font_size = (preview_font_size * multiply_factor) + add_factor;
```

example:

```
If screen resolution width is 1366px and preview box width is 310px;
=> 1366/310 = 4.406
multiply_factor = 4;
add_factor = 4;

preview_font_size = 8;
live_Screen_font_size = (8*4)+4 = 36;
```

This seems to work but not as well as I want it to. Also its obviously not correct as I haven't considered the screen height as well.

Is there a correct way for doing this?
Or is there another way to do this in C#?

Please also suggest appropriate tags for this question so that the correct people will find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want "preview", not "edit", you can save the textbox (and the text you type) to an image, and image can be easily stretched to full screen, don't have to calculate factors.

Comment: In WPF, the `ViewBox` control does exactly what you want and requires little effort, but unfortunately it has no WinForm equivalent.

Comment: @kennyzx That is a plausible solution but if the screen size is very big compared to the preview box wont the image pixelate when we stretch it to full screen? This will also take more processing power than just calculating a relative font-size for a bigger screen.

Comment: @kennyzx Ahh! Anyplace they mentioned how they scale the font?

Comment: I am afraid ViewBox has the same jaggy problem as stretched Bitmap, it just stretches the `TextBox` uniformly (same stretching factor on width and height). If you want a smooth edge on the text, you have to use bigger font size as you already did.

Comment: Found an alternate solution, I calculated the aspect ratio of the screen and changed the height of the preview box accordingly. Scaling the font using my method now produces almost exact results!